# Custom class instance creating StackOverflowException

Tags: c#

Since I wanted to learn C# programming a bit, I've just started with a normal console application whichs code you can see here ( It's quite a big file ):

http://pastebin.com/GnwBMwdt

The error only occurres when I call `MenuEntrys start = new MenuEntrys("StartGame");`

As Error It just prints `Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.`
and the "Program doesn't work anymore" window.
Does anybody know a solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what error do you receive? Make sure to provide all info when posting a question.

Comment: The problem is with the `selected` property. Its calling itself in the getter and the setter.

Comment: mike is right, just use the standard get;set; or you have to create a variable in your application to store the value (instead of using selected = value, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your property `selected` is self-referencing, which is causing an infinite loop.

When using properties, they need to reference a separate (usually private) field.

So, instead of:

```
public bool selected
{
    get { return selected; }
    set { selected = value; }
}
```

You could change it to:

```
private bool _selected
public bool Selected
{
    get { return _selected; }
    set { _selected = value; }
}
```

However, if you do not have any specific logic that needs to happen when getting or setting a value you can use an [Auto Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). Which saves you a couple lines of code.

```
public bool Selected { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you.